# Can a variable take the place of a column name in a stored procedure in sql server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have some php code that executes a stored procedure, however I have errors being thrown out when the php is executed. I am trying to figure out how to use the variable @col as the column I want to update and the value of that column to  to @val.

```
USE [***_Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertfromPHP]    Script Date: 11/11/2015 13:58:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatefromPHP] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Col varchar(25),
    @Val varchar(25),
    @DelvNumber varchar(25)

AS      
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Declare @sqlText nvarchar(max)
    set @sqlText = N'Update NWDeliverables 
    Set ' + @Col + '= ' + @Val + 'where DelvNumber= ' + @DelvNumber;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlText;
END



<?php
include_once 'DbConnect.php';

    global $connect;
    global $record3;
    global $emptyQ;
    global $rightOn;
    global $SqlArr;
    $rightOn="Thank you, your time has been inserted successfully";
    $SqlArr = $_POST['SqlArr'];

        for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($SqlArr);$i++) {

            $Empid = $SqlArr[$i][0];
            $WkEnd = $SqlArr[$i][1] ;
            $Day = $SqlArr[$i][2] ;
            $Title = $SqlArr[$i][3] ;
            $Description = $SqlArr[$i][4] ;
            $Value = $SqlArr[$i][5] ;
            $AbbrevJob = $SqlArr[$i][6] ;
            $tsql_callSP = "Execute InsertfromPHP ?,?,?,?,?,?,?";
            $stmt3 = odbc_prepare($connect, $tsql_callSP);
                if($stmt3 === false)
                {
                    throw new ErrorException(odbc_errormsg());  
                }
            $lego = odbc_execute($stmt3,array($Empid,$WkEnd,$Day,$Title,$Description,$Value,$AbbrevJob));   
                if($lego === false)
                {
                    throw new ErrorException(odbc_errormsg());
                }
        }
    odbc_close($connect);
    ?>
```

The error im recieving is this:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecute in <b>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Incuity\PSI\IS\cloud\php\ProductionStatChangeEDIT.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Incuity\PSI\IS\cloud\php\ProductionStatChangeEDIT.php:27
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Incuity\PSI\IS\cloud\php\ProductionStatChangeEDIT.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
```

Testing the Procedure using standard variable declaration and seeing the error I get:

```
declare @Col nvarchar(25)
    declare @Val nvarchar(25)
    declare @delvNumber nvarchar(25)
    set @DelvNumber = '501310-09'
    set @Val = 'AliA'
    set @Col = 'Wireman1'
    Declare @sqlText nvarchar(max)
    set @sqlText = N'Update NWDeliverables 
    Set ' + QUOTENAME(@Col) + ' = ' + @Val + ' where DelvNumber = ' + @DelvNumber
    EXEC @sqlText;

Error recieved:
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
The name 'Update NWDeliverables 
    Set [Wireman1] = AliA where DelvNumber = 501310-09' is not a valid identifier.
```

Being new to Sql Server what does this mean? What can i do to make it a valid identifier? **EDIT: I checked and I was missing the brackets around @sqlQuery. Placing those in, the valid identifier error goes away but the error im recieving now its that @Col is an invalid column and surprisingly, the error is using the value in @Val to give me the error. 
'Invalid column name 'AliA'**

Comment: Did you test your stored procedure if it runs separately?

Comment: Actually I have not. What I did test was that if my prepared statement and my php gets executed for another project where i am doing something similar without the variable as column name. And it works however this is not executing. Ill test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using QUOTENAME(@Col) in the dynamic SQL statement (instead of just @Col)

EDIT 
Try this:

```
SET @sqlText = 'UPDATE NWDeliverables
SET ' + QUOTENAME(@Col) + ' = ''' + @Val + '''
FROM NWDeliverables
WHERE DelvNumber = ''' + @DelvNumber + ''''
```

Comment: I tried the method you purposed and it did not work. Its as if, the stored procedure never fires. So I am confused on how to accomplish this. I am using this same method without the dynamic column name for another application and using a prepared statment to execute a stored procedure work beautifully, accomplishing the task I developed it for. But here, it fails to even fire and I am assuming it is because of the @col variable.